# Renaming metrics in service monitor

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, monitoring, prometheus

after reading [this](https://alexandrev.medium.com/how-to-change-the-names-of-your-metrics-in-prometheus-b78497efb5de) article I'm trying to cleanup metrics going out of Spark 3.0.1. Here is my servicemonitor.yml file:

```
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    app: spark3
    release:  prometheus
  name: spark3-servicemonitor
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 5s
    port: spark-ui
    path: /metrics/prometheus
    relabelings:
    # Rename metrics
      - sourceLabels: [__name__]
        targetLabel: __name__
        regex: 'metrics_spark_driver_.+_StreamingMetrics_([a-zA-Z_]{1,})_Value'
        replacement: 'spark_driver_$1'
  namespaceSelector:
    matchNames:
    - default
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      spark-version: "3"
```

I expect the following transformation:
metrics_spark_driver_whateverappid_StreamingMetrics_streaming_lastCompletedBatch_totalDelay_Value -> spark_driver_streaming_lastCompletedBatch_totalDelay however the relabelling does not seem to work. Could you please assist me on this subject?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `relabelings` must be named `metricRelabelings` according to the [spec](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/552d86a2713f6653146674f3598955a375b93099/bundle.yaml#L10224). Note that the yaml format of the ServiceMonitors does not use the same key names as the corresponding prometheus config (but it is still valid yaml).